# Use another parameter for tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to define a new `Tikz` `style` that uses the same parameters as the object you used. I managed to get the `line width`, but I am not able to get `line cap`, for example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\tikzset{%
    glow/.style n args={2}{%
      preaction={#1, draw, line cap=% the same as the line: in this case round%
             , line width=\pgflinewidth+.1*#2, opacity=1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw[line width=2pt, glow={black}{1pt}, line cap=round](0,0)--++(\textwidth-20pt,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for my understanding: Is this glowing line all you want to do? If so, why the effort of passing parameters, which you could enter (or define) directly? Thank you for clarifying

Comment: I want to change the style based on the line I use on, and adjust the color and the thickness every time.

Comment: Do you mean: with different parameters on every page?

Comment: Different parameter for every line

Comment: Hm, I think you should add this extra-Information to your question, together with extended code, and perhaps a sketch if useful. At the moment I‘m not sure, e.g. if and where you would place text (as nodes?) or other Tikz/Latex objects. Your question is a good place to clarify. Thank you

Comment: Hmm, problematic, the line cap will be installed as an option but these options won't be activated much later. The pre in preaction is really very pre. I don't see a good solution without patching something that might lead to bigger problems somewhere else. The easiest would be to tackle the problem from the other side and re-define: `\tikzset{line cap/.code=\csname pgfset#1cap\endcsname}`. Again, this might make things weird when the path contains nodes or other nested paths.

Comment: Could you flip it? Make the glowing the normal path and the normal path a postaction? Then a `line cap` setting will apply to both.

Comment: Or could you make the glow the `postaction`, but draw it below the normal path?